# Targeting one item in an Array ( React, useState)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react. I created an array of items with each switch element, the problem is: when I click on one item all items are activated at once!

```
const dashboardItems = ["news", "notifications", "letters"];

const Settings = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("settings");
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <SideMenu class="dashboard-settings">
      <SideMenu.Item>
        <SideMenu.Header>{t("Dashboard Settings")}</SideMenu.Header>
      </SideMenu.Item>
      {dashboardItems.map((dashboardItem) => (
        <SideMenu.Item key={dashboardItem}>
          {t(dashboardItem)}{" "}
          <Switch
            onClick={handleClick}
            status={isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}
          />
        </SideMenu.Item>
      ))}
    </SideMenu>
  );
};
```

I tried many solutions I found through search but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a single value for all items. Instead convert the `isActive` state to an object (like the example), or array (use indexes instead of item), and toggle the item on the object.

The state:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState({});
```

The switch:

```
<Switch 
  onClick={() => {
    setIsActive(s => ({ 
      ...s, 
      [dashboardItem]: !s[dashboardItem]
    }))
  } 
  status={isActive[dashboardItem] ? 'active' : 'inactive'}
/>
```